# show json file in an alert on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple log in at the top of my page that enables a user to enter a code - the code then reads the json file and pulls up the specific user of that code. I do have it showing in the alert, however I want the alert hidden before the user enters the code and displayed if the code is valid.  In my json file I have the users code (which is currently named id) and when that is entered their name displays in the alert box. If nothing or an invalid code that is not apart of my code display I want an error alert to display.
This is what I have so far:

the log in text button:

```
<div class="alert alert-info"><input type="text" id="userName" value> <button type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button></div>
```

the welcome/login alert:

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="loginalert"<strong>Welcome</strong></div>
```

the error alert:

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger" id="ErrorMessageAlert" <strong>Error</strong>invalid</div>
```

and the script ive been working on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#loginalert").hide();    
$("#ErrorMessageAlert").hide();
$("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
$.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
      var id = $('#userName').val();
      for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
        if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
          $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');      
            $("#loginalert").show();
        }else
        {
            $("#ErrorMessageAlert").show();
        }
      );
        }
      }
   });
}); });
```

A user from the json looks like {"user":[{"ID" : "001","name": "Zara Ali"}

So when the user writes in 001 the alert will display with that name
If the user enters nothing or an invalid code I want the error message to display.

Many thanks

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Why not use `$.ajax` and its `error` and `success` functions to do that instead of this`$.getJSON` bit?

Comment: i want an error to appear when the user doesnt enter anything or enters somethin invalid - the script doesnt work. On ready both of the alerts appear, I want them hidden and then the welcome one shown if the user enters the correct id or the error one if nothing is showing or is invalid

Comment: put if condition before `$.getJSON` to check !="" .

Comment: You are not closing the `<div>` tags for `loginalert` and `ErrorMessageAlert`

Comment: put them `style="display:none"` by default and if error then use .show();

Comment: apologies that was an error on my belhalf entering this into stack overflow, they are cloded on my editor though

Comment: this was an error when entering into stack overflow, I have taken this out now

Comment: looks like a bracket/parenthesis mixup. Check to make sure they all match up, that logic should work

Comment: I was thinking the same, not sure whats wrong with it been trying for a wile to get it to work

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6db1yzz3/)

Comment: Hi mjr thank you for your answer, however on page load both of the results are displayed and another two display ( both the welcome and the invalid one) when a valid users id is entered

Comment: Did you copy what's in that fiddle? On page load neither is displayed. But it displays both when attempting to login because your if/else block makes the error alert show if a valid id is not found. As @somethinghere said, you need to find a way to allow only one login at a time, maybe by stopping the loop when a valid id is found.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier to simply use ajax to get the JSON, as it makes your code more readable - that, and indentation and line breaks. The below should work but cannot be tested on Stack Overflow itself as it does not allow AJAX requests. The reason to use this piece of jQuery is that it has some neat built-in features and since this looks like it might be a login form, you might want to post some data over the web as well, which gets easier for later with `ajax`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#loginalert, #ErrorMessageAlert').hide();
  
  $("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
    // Every time you click the button, hide all alerts again
    $('#loginalert, #ErrorMessageAlert').hide();
  
    $.ajax({
      url: 'result.json',
      success: function(msg){
          for(var i = 0; i < msg.user.length; i++){
            if(msg.user[i].ID == id){
              $('#loginalert')
                  .html('<p> Welcome: ' + msg.user[i].name + '</p>')
                  .show();
            } else {
              $('#ErrorMessageAlert').show();
            }
          }
      }, 
      error: function(e){
        $('#ErrorMessageAlert').show();
      }
    });
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-info">
  <input type="text" id="userName" value> 
  <button type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="loginalert"<strong>Welcome</strong></div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" id="ErrorMessageAlert" <strong>Error</strong>invalid</div>
```

There also seems to be a bit of a problem here in logic - can you have *multiple users* logged in at once in the same place? If not, then why are we looping through the results? You should return just one user, not nested. If you now get back multiple users, then only the last users name will be displayed, and that's odd. I would either change your JSOn to return only one user by default, or modify the javascript to only check for one:

```
success: function(msg){
    if(msg.user[0] && msg.user[0].ID == id){
        $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + msg.user[0].name + '</p>').show();
    } else {
        $('#ErrorMessageAlert').show();
    }
}
```

The major thing is structure, though. Use tabs, line-breaks, and any kind of visual information to show what step nests in what other step, making your code easier to read at a glance.

Comment: i understand what you mean. I have been trying another cript, this gets the welcome user alert to show after the certain id has been entered:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();    
  $("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
   //console.log("clicked login");
  $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
   var id = $('#userName').val();
  //console.log(id);
  for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) { if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
 $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');      
 //show the alert after loading the information
$("#loginalert").stop().fadeIn('slow').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
$('#contact').fadeIn('slow');

Comment: however when i hide the error messageand  put the else if for this it doesnt appear

Comment: @laurajs I have a feeling you are overcomplicating this. I would tell you to _not_ use jQuery to do your animations - just use a className and use CSS transitions so your javascript logic stays as simple as possible and as separated from the visual element as possible. For example, why not one have one `message` div where you can replace the contents and add a class to style it correctly? Then use the above script to simply add a class and message on success or failure. `Keep it Simple, Stupid` (KISS) :)